# How to pass parameters to stored procedures in Azure CosmosDB in the portal

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I've created a simple stored procedure by going to the CosmosDB account in Azure portal and then going to Script Explorer and selecting Create Stored Procedure. The following is the stored procedure:

```
function saySomething(text) {
var context = getContext();
var response = context.getResponse();

response.setBody(text);
}
```

When I click on Save & Execute, it saves it correctly but fails to execute because I didn't pass the parameter correctly. I had created another stored procedure that doesn't take parameters and it worked fine.

Is there a way to execute stored procedures and pass parameters within the portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it saves it correctly but fails to execute because I didn't pass the parameter correctly

I create a stored procedure using your code, and it works for me if I pass the parameter in **Inputs** field. Please make sure you pass the parameter before you execute your stored procedure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't notice the input field.